# Take two numbers as input, a width and height. Create a square where there are WIDTH numbers on each line, and HEIGHT rows

Tags: python, range

This is the code that I have so far. My out put needs to look similar to:

```
Please enter the width: 5

Please enter the height: 2

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10
```

or another example would be

```
Please enter the width: 2

Please enter the height: 3

1 2 

3 4

5 6
```

```
def main():

    # variables width and height
    width  = 0
    height = 0

    # Takes input from user for variables
    width  = int( input( "Please enter the width: " ) )
    height = int( input( "Please enter the height: " ) )

    i = 0
    while i < height:
        for x in range( 1, ( width * height ) + 1 ):
            print( x, "", end = "" )

main()
```

Currently my code prints out everything in a single line.

I can't figure out how to have the line keep printing numbers until it reaches the width, drop down a new line and continue until the height is reached also.

Comment: add a `print()` after the `for` loop...

Comment: I would say that you need two `for` loops, one nested inside the other... the inner one would print `width` numbers, then a `\n`, increasing each time the variable that stores the number to be printed. The outer one would just repeat this `height` times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my suggestion is to use nested for loops. In pseudocode,

```
set the number variable to 0
for each line,
    for each number in the line,
        increase the number
        and print it
    end each line with a \n
```

Comment: Nope! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use modulo to find the place for a new line:

```
if i%width == 0:
     print("")
```

This way you only need one counter to increment. Here's a complete example to print a neat box with a uniform shape by checking the length of the digit to print:

```
def main():
    # variables width and height
    width = 0
    height = 0

    # Takes input from user for variables
    width = int(input("Please enter the width: "))
    height = int(input("Please enter the height: "))

    i = 0
    max_num = width * height
    while i < max_num:
        i += 1
        needed_space = len(str(max_num)) - len(str(i))
        print(i, " " * needed_space, end='')
        if i % width == 0:
            print("")


main()
```